# nutch crawler relative urls problem

Tags: java, lucene, solr, nutch

Has any one experience a problem with the way the standard html parser plugin handles relative urls? There is a site - http://xxxx/asp/list_books.asp?id_f=11327
and when browsing a link with its href set to
'?id_r=442&id=41&order='
a browser will naturally take you to
http://xxxx/asp/list_books.asp?id_r=442&id=41&order=

However, in nutch when the outlinks are parsed from the page the link ends up being
http://xxxx/asp/?id_r=442&id=41&order=

which of course is broken. So why is the list_books.asp gone?

Comment: i found same bug in OmniFind http://omnifind.ibm.yahoo.net/

Answer (score 3):

A [bug](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/NUTCH-566) has already been logged for this. Take a look.

Comment: this patch helped me - https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/NUTCH-797?page=com.atlassian.jira.plugin.system.issuetabpanels:all-tabpanel